TL431 - How to use Rbias
I am trying to understand the idea behind the Rbias used in the TL431 feedback circuits.
According to my research it is used for bias current for the tl431 to properly use its funtion. The point that I want to understand is :

How does Rbias come into play ? like when does it conducts current and why.

How to calculate its value based on which voltage ? the calculation that I saw is for around 1mA of bias current of tl431 and considering around 1V of forward voltage drop of LED , Rbias is 1V / 1mA however Rbias is connected to cathode of tl431 and this node seems like 0V or ground ? I didn't understand how they calculated without knowing the cathode voltage of tl431 ?



Source: https://www.onsemi.com/pub/collateral/tnd381-d.pdf

Isn't that explained on page 12 of the document you linked? Other pages have example values for Ibias.

why do we ignore the cathode voltage of TL431, the current through Rbias should also be dependent on Cathode voltage of TL431. consider for example the minimum cathode voltage of 2.5 when it is on, wouldn't it be 1V-2.5V ? @Justme

On page 16 of that Onsemi document is a graph showing how insufficient bias current through the TL431 causes its open-loop gain to drop by over 10dB at lower frequencies:

While I don't know how accurate that claim is, this problem would be manifest when \$V_{OUT}\$ is close to the threshold where the TL431 is just conducting and the LED barely has \$V_F=1V\$ across it. LED impedance varies significantly around that point, becoming very high as LED voltage drops under its \$V_F\$ even only slightly. When LED impedance is high (\$V_{LED}<V_F\$), it won't pass sufficient current to obtain the best open-loop gain shown in that graph.
Take for instance the case where \$R_1\$ and \$R_{lower}\$ are chosen to have the TL431 begin conducting at \$V_{OUT}=4V\$, so it behaves like a 4V zener diode (D2 below), LED \$V_F\approx 1V\$, and \$R_{BIAS}\$ is absent:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
As I sweep V1 through 5V, at lower voltages D2 current dips below 1mA:

Adding the bias resistor \$R_{BIAS}\$ provides a low impedance (1kΩ here) current path bypassing the high impedance LED, for the case where LED voltage is close to or below its \$V_F\$. When the LED is more strongly forward biased, it becomes the dominant path for current. In that case, LED voltage (also the voltage across \$R_{BIAS}\$) is clamped to a maximum of 1V or so, and current through \$R_{BIAS}\$ stays clamped at 1mA. That is, 1mA through \$R_{BIAS}\$, the rest through the LED:

simulate this circuit
The same sweep again, but showing LED current (orange) also:

The DC operating point of this circuit is around \$V_{OUT}=5V\$, which would be the case if the application were a 5V power supply, and no doubt you could use this design without \$R_{BIAS}\$, but by choosing \$R_{BIAS}\$ to pass 1mA at quiescence, you are getting the best DC and low-frequency performance possible from the TL431, while simultaneously operating the TL431 under datasheet-recommended conditions, that \$I_K\ge 1mA\$.

\$R_{BIAS}\$ desensitizes the optocoupler's LED to overall current flow. As mentioned by The Photon, the TL431 needs at least 1 mA for proper operation but, way before 1 mA is flowing through the optocoupler's LED it can activate. The LED may need just a hundred micro-amps to turn on so, you solve this by using \$R_{BIAS}\$ to take the bulk of the 1 mA needed for the TL431 to operate and leave a little bit of current to run parallel through the optocoupler LED.
The paper you linked shows that they chose an optocoupler with a 1 volt threshold LED: -

And this means that when 1 volt appears across the LED, \$R_{BIAS}\$ handles the main bulk of the operating current. Of course, you need to study the LED in the optocoupler's data sheet to check its threshold voltage.

why do we ignore the cathode voltage of TL431, the current through Rbias should also be dependent on Cathode voltage of TL431.  consider for example the minimum cathode voltage of 2.5 when it is on, wouldn't it be 1V-2.5V ? which is weird  @Andy aka

If you looked at the TL431 data sheet you would see that the minimum "on" current is about 2V (it needs that much voltage to bias the internal circuits.

@CarlRutschow yes you are quite correct. Figure 9-2 in the datasheet confirms that.

@Mhan I don't get what you are saying. What would be 1V-2.5V?

If you connect a resistor between 5V and Ground, what would you say ? you will say 5V across resistor right? what if you change the Ground let say 2V , what will happen, the voltage drop across resistor is 3V. IF SO, the cathode of the TL431 is not zero, I will suggest you to think about my previous question again @Andy aka

@mhan you are asking some form of question in comments that I have no idea how this fits in with your original question. Asking questions in comments is always difficult but you have made the error of saying "when it is on, wouldn't it be 1V-2.5V" and I have no idea what that means. I mean maybe the question is "consider for example the minimum cathode voltage of 2.5 when it is on, wouldn't it be 1V-2.5V" and I still don't understand what you are getting at. Your question(s) don't parse in a sensible way. What voltage are you talking about that equals 1V-2.5V

@Mhan I think you may be confusing voltages relative to 0 volts with potential difference voltages.

The cathode of the TL431 is not 0V or ground, its minimum is about 2V.
The cathode voltage will be determined by the value of Vout and and at what level current the opto LED requires when it is regulating the power supply output voltage.
Below is the LTspice sim of the circuit for arbitrary (not necessarily optimum) resistor values for the circuit controlling a regulator to a 5V output:
Note the voltages and currents as it starts regulating at a Vout of 5V.


But the cathode voltage of the TL431 is minimum 2 or 2.5 V and the voltage drop on the LED is 1V approximately, IF So, that means current should flow from 1V to 2V which doesn't make sense, this is the point that I dont understand @Carl Rutschow

@mhan you have 1 volt across the LED and say 2.5 volts across the TL431. That means that the anode of the LED has 3.5 volts. Don't confuse absolute voltages that are relative to 0 volts with potential differences.

The TL431 (I looked at the TI datasheet, not On Semi, but it should be very similar) needs 1 mA cathode current to regulate accurately.
Rbias allows you to provide that current, even when you adjust R_lower or R_1 to shut off the LED.
(This is somewhat explained on slide 16 of the document you linked)

But the cathode voltage of the TL431 is minimum 2 or 2.5 V and the voltage drop on the LED is 1V approximately, IF So, that means current should flow from 1V to 2V which doesn't make sense, this is the point that I dont understand @The Photon

@Mhan, it's possible to adjust the cathode voltage higher. Which would lead to shutting off the LED.
